# Dependent methods in the same class run out of order only when included in a "testng suite"; running class independently respects the dependency

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a class with dependent methods using the TestNG annotation

```
dependsOnMethods
```

The test runs fine 100% of the time if I simply run it as a TestNG Test from the package.

When I include the test in a TestNG Suite, the methods run out of order.  Yes, I am using:

```
  <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
```

in my .xml file.

Every other test in the suite respects the method ordering and run without issue.  Is there any known information on why this might be occurring?

Code for the test case:

```
@Test(groups={ "Administration"})
public class RoleCrudTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest
{
protected static SeleniumActionHelper action;

    @Test
    public void inactiveRole() throws Exception
    {
        SeleniumHelper helper = new SeleniumHelper();
        action = new SeleniumActionHelper(driver);

        helper.login();

        String roleUrl = navigateToUrl("role/roles.xhtml");
        driver.get(roleUrl);

        assertEquals("Role:", findElementBySelector("span.portletButtonHeader").getText());

        WebElement roleName = findElementById("roleName");
        assertFalse(roleName.isEnabled());

        WebElement deptId = findElementById("deptid");
        assertFalse(deptId.isEnabled());
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "inactiveRole")
    public void createRole() throws Exception
    {
        WebElement addButton = findElementById("add");
        addButton.click();

        waitUntilAjaxRequestCompletes();

        WebElement roleName = findElementById("roleName");
        roleName.click();
        roleName.sendKeys("AAAAAAAA");

        WebElement deptId = findElementByXpath("(//button[@type='button'])[3]");
        deptId.click();

        WebElement dept = findElementByXpath("//div[@id='department_panel']/ul/li[2]");
        dept.click();

        WebElement checkbox = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:1']/div/span/div/div");
        checkbox.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement save = findElementById("save");
        save.click();

        assertEquals("Role saved successfully", findElementBySelector("div.ui-growl-message > p").getText());
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "createRole")
    public void editUndo() throws Exception
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement tableSort = findElementByXpath("//th[@id='tableSection:rolesListWrapped:j_idt85']/div/span[2]");
        tableSort.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement createdRole = findElementByXpath("//tbody[@id='tableSection:rolesListWrapped_data']/tr[1]/td/div");
        createdRole.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement roleName = findElementById("roleName");
        roleName.click();
        roleName.clear();
        roleName.sendKeys("edited");

        WebElement deptId = findElementByXpath("(//button[@type='button'])[3]");
        deptId.click();

        WebElement dept = findElementByXpath("//div[@id='department_panel']/ul/li[3]");
        dept.click();

        WebElement checkbox = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:1']/div/span/div/div/span");
        checkbox.click();

        WebElement checkbox2 = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:0']/div/span/div/div");
        checkbox2.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement undo = findElementById("cancel");
        undo.click();

        String text = findElementById("roleName").getAttribute("value");
        String oldtext = "AAAAAAAA";

        assertTrue(text.equals(oldtext));
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "editUndo")
    public void editRole() throws Exception
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement createdRole = findElementByXpath("//tbody[@id='tableSection:rolesListWrapped_data']/tr[1]/td/div");
        createdRole.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement roleName = findElementById("roleName");
        roleName.click();
        roleName.clear();
        roleName.sendKeys("AAAAAAAAedited");

        WebElement deptId = findElementByXpath("(//button[@type='button'])[3]");
        deptId.click();

        WebElement dept = findElementByXpath("//div[@id='department_panel']/ul/li[3]");
        dept.click();

        WebElement checkbox = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:1']/div/span/div/div/span");
        checkbox.click();

        WebElement checkbox2 = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:0']/div/span/div/div");
        checkbox2.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement save = findElementById("save");
        save.click();

        assertEquals("Role saved successfully", findElementBySelector("div.ui-growl-message > p").getText());
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "editRole")
    public void deleteRole() throws Exception
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement deleteButton = findElementById("tableSection:delete");
        deleteButton.click();

        WebElement deleteConfirm = findElementById("confirmDelete:yes");
        deleteConfirm.click();

        Thread.sleep(500);

        assertEquals("Role deleted successfully", findElementBySelector("div.ui-growl-message > p").getText());

        waitUntilAjaxRequestCompletes();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`dependsOnMethods` is what you want, not `preserve-order` (actually, `dependsOnGroups` is recommended over `dependsOnMethods`, but both will work).

If you have a small test case showing the problem, please post it